# When we assign value jQuery event call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two text fields:

```
 <input type="text" id="ex_1" class="update">

 <input type="text" id="ex_2" class="update">
```

I want when I assign value:

```
 jQuery("#ex_1").val(12);
```

`jQuery` event called like below but not on the change but on assign value:

```
 jQuery(".update").change();



  jQuery(".update").live('keyup change', function()
 {
   alert(jQuery(this).val());
 }
```

On the assignment of value `jQuery` event called?

Comment: and how are you assigning the value

Comment: when i assign value like that jQuery("#ex_1").val(12); i want an jquery event called

Comment: `jQuery("#ex_1").val(12).trigger('change');`

Comment: You have to use `jQuery("#ex_1").val(12).change();` or `jQuery("#ex_1").val(12).trigger('change');`

Comment: you want to fire the change event without manually triggering it?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for>

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="../JS/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("input").change(function () {
 alert('in');  // do you stuff here
 });

  $("#Button1").click(function () {
  $("input").val(12);
  $("input").trigger("change");
  });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="ex_1" class="update">
<input type="text" id="ex_2" class="update">
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**.trigger("change") will invoke the elements change function.**

In the code above, on click of the button the val will be changed and also the change function will be triggered.

Syntax :

> $("selector_of_element").trigger("event_function");

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this

```
$(".update").keyup(function () {
        $(this).trigger("change");
    });

    $(".update").change(function () {
        alert("change");
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UY6Q7/16/)

Comment: but i assign value like that jQuery("#ex_1").val(12);

Comment: i assing value run time in jquery function ex_name(){
jQuery("#ex_1").val(12); 
}

Comment: i want when i assing value an event called

Answer (score 1):

The change event fires only if the value is changed by the user interaction.

If you want to fire event then you have manually trigger event. So use `.change();` or`.trigger('change');`

Answer (score 1):

If you're programatically assigning value, you'll have to manually trigger the change event. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808180/how-to-select-jquery-drop-down-val-and-trigger-the-event/5808221#5808221) answer.

Try this:

```
jQuery('#ex_1').val(12).change();
```

Comment: i do not call with the name of id because my id is dynamic

Comment: How are you setting the value? Could you post the code?